# How does Jmeter calculate throughput for multiple samples?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-5.0

[Multiple samples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbAMD.png)

I have been able to calculate the throughput with single sample accurately but with multiple samples i am not able to get the value that is in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

According to [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html):

> **Throughput** is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
>
> The formula is: `Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).`

So you need to measure your test duration and then divide the number of the requests by the test duration.

The exact implementation of all the calculated metrics lives in [Calculator](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/util/Calculator.java) class, the [function which returns the throughput](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/util/Calculator.java#L260) looks like:

```
private double getRatePerSecond(long value) {
    if (elapsedTime > 0) {
        return value / ((double) elapsedTime / 1000); // 1000 = millisecs/sec
    }
    return 0.0;
}
```

You might also be interested in [What is the Relationship Between Users and Hits Per Second?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-relationship-between-users-and-hits-second/) article

Comment: i am not able to get the value that is in the throughput column which is 17.2/hour. Dividing total number of request (2) by total time (12230) and multiplying it with 1000 gives me 0.1635322976287817 then further multiplying it with 60 gives me 9.811937857726901.